# Flutter Hive Adapter for Geopoint

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, geopoints, flutter-hive

I'm storing a geopoint in firestore and I'm trying to retrieve it with my Hive adapter. However, Im getting

> `Cannot write, unknown type: GeoPoint. Did you forget to register an adapter?`

I'm registering the adapter so that's not the issue. is the geopoint part of the data.

This is my hive field

```
@HiveField(5)
  Map<String, dynamic> location;
```

This is how it looks in my Firestore DB

[image]

Has anybody faced this issue or there a way to create an adapter for this to be used by Hive/Firestore?

Comment: Actually I think I narrowed down my issue. I need to create an adapter for GeoPoint (external source file) and  I do not know how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

To create a Gepoint Adapter you need to have a model that can be adapted.
I am not sure how you handle the data stored in that geopoint, and I guess I would simply parse the data in some way.
So I am assuming this model:

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'location.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Location {
  @HiveField(0)
  String geohash;

  @HiveField(1)
  GeoPoint geoPoint;

  @HiveField(2)
  String locationPreviewURL;
}
```

Notice the **part 'location.g.dart';** .
This will be used by the generator to create an adapter in the end.

Create a model for GeoPoint containing Types Hive can handle, so I am assuming the geodata part of your value is a String for now.
You need to decide how to handle that type of value.
I'll focus on the adapter part for now.

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'geopoint.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class GeoPoint {
  @HiveField(0)
  String geodata;
}
```

With that in place, go to your terminal and run

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

to create the adapters.
Note that you will need to recreate those when you change the HiveModels .
You should use

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

for that.

Finally you need to register your Adapters so Hive can make use of them.
So before opening any boxes, usually when initializing the app call

```
Hive.registerAdapter(LocationAdapter());
Hive.registerAdapter(GeoPointAdapter());
```