# How to create Hive adapter for XFile class

Tags: flutter, imagepicker, flutter-hive

I'm trying to store custom object that has variable storing list of `XFile`'s; cross platform image representation from package called `image_picker` version `0.8.4+3`. When writing an error occurs saying that im missing Adapter for `XFile` which is understandable, but I'm having hard time deciding how to declare such Adapter for external source file class.

This is my `Receipt` class that has some list of `XFile`'s.

Note: I've removed nonmeaningful variables from snippet.

```dart
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Receipt extends HiveObject with EquatableMixin {
  Receipt({
    List<XFile>? files,
  }) {
    this.files = files ?? <XFile>[];
  }

  @HiveField(6)
  late final List<XFile> files;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        files,
      ];
}
```

Now I was thinking about two possible solutions; one - copy whole source code from `XFile`, add `HiveType` and `HiveField` decorators and generate adapter from that or two - create class that will extend from XFile and add decorators something like this:

```dart
@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class XFileAdapter extends XFile with HiveObjectMixin {
    // access fields and add decorators here 
}
```

but I have no clue how to add decorators to these field without overriding every one of them. And even if I knew how to do that, it turns out that `XFile`'s doesn't have its own variables I've could add Hive decorators to, it simply takes paramethers and passes them down to `XFileBase` class since it further decides what to do with them.

Very similar question has been asked [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62845643/flutter-hive-adapter-for-geopoint) but the only aswer suggests creating new class from scratch that imitates source class which is not solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think creating a new `MyXFile` class as you suggested might be the way to go. But as you've said you will need to override the properties you want to keep in hive. This code seems to be working as intended:

### Code

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/adapters.dart';

part 'my_xfile.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class MyXFile extends XFile {
  @override
  @HiveField(1)
  final String path;

  @override
  @HiveField(2)
  final String? mimeType;

  @HiveField(3)
  final String? _name;

  /// The base implementation of `XFileBase.name` throws an
  /// [UnimplementedError] so we are overriding it to return a known
  /// [_name] value.
  @override
  String get name {
    if (_name != null) {
      return _name!;
    }
    return super.name;
  }

  @HiveField(4)
  final int? _length;

  /// The base implementation of `XFileBase.length()` throws an
  /// [UnimplementedError] so we are overriding it to return a known
  /// [_length] value.
  @override
  Future<int> length() {
    return _length != null ? Future.value(_length!) : super.length();
  }

  @HiveField(5)
  final Uint8List? bytes;

  @HiveField(6)
  final DateTime? _lastModified;

  /// The base implementation of `XFileBase.lastModified()` throws an
  /// [UnimplementedError] so we are overriding it to return a known
  /// [_lastModified] value.
  @override
  Future<DateTime> lastModified() {
    return _lastModified != null
        ? Future.value(_lastModified!)
        : super.lastModified();
  }

  MyXFile(
    this.path, {
    this.mimeType,
    String? name,
    int? length,
    this.bytes,
    DateTime? lastModified,
  })  : _name = name,
        _length = length,
        _lastModified = lastModified,
        super(
          path,
          mimeType: mimeType,
          name: name,
          length: length,
          bytes: bytes,
          lastModified: lastModified,
        );
}
```

By using this I've been able to save and retrieve my object `MyXFile` and as it is extending `XFile` you should be able to use it the same way.

Then instead of having a `List<XFile>? files` in your `Receipt` class you will need a `List<MyXFile>? files`.

Comment: Wonderful, worked like a charm after small changes. Before just copy paste I've tried to do the same by myself but even tho I've seen that exceptions are thrown I wouldn't know that I can simply override them like you did, thank you so much.